# ESB WSO2 Java - I want to modify a value from a json file with Class Mediator

Tags: java, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

So I have this Class Mediator for my API:

```
public class CheckUser extends AbstractMediator {

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        String age_value = (String) context.getProperty("age_value");
        context.setProperty("age_value", 33);
        log.info("#### The new age value is: " + context.getProperty("age_value"));

        return true;
    }
}
```

And I want to modify the age value in the response

Initial json file:

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "name": "Andrei",
            "adress": "Tudor Vladimirescu, nr2",
            "cnp": 123456789,
            "age": 22,
            "valid": "Yes"
        }
    }
}
```

Desired json file:

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "name": "Andrei",
            "adress": "Tudor Vladimirescu, nr2",
            "cnp": 123456789,
            "age": 33,
            "valid": "Yes"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to do this with the `ScriptMediator` It is a very useful mediator and allows you to use a programming language. Your example will look like below. I used `nashornJs` here as there is no problem with number formatting (age is still integer not a decimal).

```
 <script language="nashornJs"><![CDATA[
    var log = mc.getServiceLog(); 
    var age_value = mc.getProperty('age_value');
    var msg = mc.getPayloadJSON();
    msg.data.user.age = parseInt(age_value);
    mc.setPayloadJSON(message);
    log.info("#### The new age value is: " + mc.getProperty('age_value'));]]>
</script>
```

If you are still not convinced and want to use `Class Mediator`, you have to use appropriate json conversion libraries.

Comment: I want to use Class Mediator for practice purpose only because in the future I have to use it for more complex things

Comment: If so, I suggest to look and study mediators implementation on github, for example: https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/builtin/JSONTransformMediator.java

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing mediators to achieve your requirement(enrich, payload factory etc). But if you really want to use a class mediator, you can do something like below.

```
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {

    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
    JSONObject jsonPayload = new JSONObject(JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(axis2MessageContext));
    JSONObject data = jsonPayload.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("user");
    data.remove("age");
    data.put("age",33);
    jsonPayload.getJSONObject("data").put("user",data);
    try {
        JsonUtil.getNewJsonPayload(axis2MessageContext,jsonPayload.toString(),true,true);
    } catch (AxisFault axisFault) {
        axisFault.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here, I have used additional dependency to construct the JSON objects.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version> 
 </dependency>
```